# .Net XML PackageReference with constraint

Tags: c#, .net, xml, nuget-package, dependency-management

From time to time, some packages need to be updated to fix vulnerabilities raised by alerts.

As an example: 
`package name: "Contoso", affected versions: >=3.0.0 and <3.1.3, patched version: 3.1.3.`

As I use DotNet, my solution's packages are shown in the project XML file in the following format: 
`<PackageReference Include="Contoso" Version="x.y.z" />`

In spite of the fact that I want to update the package, I don't want to set it as version "3.1.3" since I have a few different uses for it. 
There are some packages/solutions that depend on "Consto" (example) package version 1.x.x, 
but there are other packages/solutions that depend on version 3.x.x. 
In those cases, setting the version to 3.1.3 may be problematic.

Can the current in use packages be constrained by range? As an example: 
`< ... Condition=" '$(CurrentInUseVersion)' >= '3.0.0' & '$(CurrentInUseVersion)' < '3.1.3' " Version="3.1.3" .../>`

I appreciate your help in advance!

Didn't work- 
`<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.WebApiCompatShim" Version="1.0.4" Condition="'$(PackageVersion)' >= '1.0.0' And '$(PackageVersion)' < '1.0.4'" />`